# C# Coroutine repeating a specific part?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a cookie clicker game for a school project and for my achievement system I want to have a simple animation pop up, and text in a separate menu script that already works perfectly fine.

The issue I am having is that the first two achievements work fine, but after the second one pops up, it just repeats with "Test B" and "Test C" repeating infinitely in the console.

I've tried to have values try to make an 'if' statement void but nothing seems to work.

I feel like I am just eating my own tail with all of the Boolean values I created to get this far.

This is my code below, from only a single script in my Unity file.
Hopefully this has enough information needed for guidance.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Achievements : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject achievementBanner;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achievementText;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achievementBannerAnimation;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achievementTextAnimation;


    [SerializeField] GameObject achiOne;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achiTwo;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achiThree;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achiFour;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achiFive;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achiSix;


    [SerializeField] public static int achiementcount;
    bool achievementrec = false;
    bool achievementani = false;
    bool achidone = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        achiOne.SetActive(false);
        achiTwo.SetActive(false);
        achiThree.SetActive(false);
        achiFour.SetActive(false);
        achiFive.SetActive(false);
        achiSix.SetActive(false);
        achievementBanner.SetActive(false);
        achievementText.SetActive(false);
        achievementText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Achievement: First cookie!";

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        print(achiementcount);
        print(achidone);
        if (achiementcount == 1)
        {
            if (!achievementani)
            {
                if (!achievementrec)
                {
                    print("Test D");
                    achiOne.SetActive(true);
                    achievementBanner.SetActive(true);
                    achievementText.SetActive(true);
                    StartCoroutine(AchievementGot());
                    ///achidone = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (achidone == true)
        {
            ///print("Test");
            ///achidone = false;
            if (achiementcount == 2)
                    {
                        achievementText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Achievement: First Clicker!";
                        achievementani = false;
                        achievementrec = false;
                        if (!achievementani)
                        {
                            if (!achievementrec)
                            {
                                print("Test C");
                                achiTwo.SetActive(true);
                                achievementBanner.SetActive(true);
                                achievementText.SetActive(true);
                                ///achidone = true;
                                StartCoroutine(AchievementGot());
                            }
                        }
                    }
        }
        
        ///print(achidone);
        if (achidone == true)
        {
            ///achidone = false;
            if (achiementcount == 3)
                    {
                        achievementText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Achievement: First Upgrade!";
                        achievementani = false;
                        achievementrec = false;
                        if (!achievementani)
                        {
                            if (!achievementrec)
                            {
                                print("Test A");
                                achiThree.SetActive(true);
                                achievementBanner.SetActive(true);
                                achievementText.SetActive(true);
                                StartCoroutine(AchievementGot());
                            }
                        }
                    }
        }   
    }
    IEnumerator AchievementGot()
    {
        ///achievementrec = true;
        achievementBannerAnimation.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Achievement");
        achievementTextAnimation.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("AchiText");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(6);
        achidone = true;
        print("Test B");
        ///print(achidone);
        achievementBanner.SetActive(false);
        achievementText.SetActive(false);
        achievementani = true;
        achievementrec = true;
        ///achidone = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should rework it all thinking in slightly different way. Will give you just an initial direction. Make component say called `Achievement` that contains text, animation, done, etcetera. And make that as a prefab containing all that. Then have your current `Achievements` component only to deal with a `List<Achievement>`  (added through inspector). This way you will get rid of most if branching and instead use `for` loops that operates on the list.

Comment: _[Why coroutines are evil](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2022/10/06/implementing-time-based-delays-in-unity-3d/)_.

Comment: When using `static` in Unity beware - [thar be dragons](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/DomainReloading.html).   See also _[Details of disabling Domain and Scene Reload](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfigurableEnterPlayModeDetails.html)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should use a List/Array.

Then you probably also want to show the banner only **ONCE** when the achievement is unlocked the first time so you should also keep track of which one you already showed.

E.g. something like

```
[Serializable]
public class Achievement
{
    // text to display in the banner
    public string Label; 
    // the object to enable
    public GameObject GameObject;
    // has this been achieved
    public bool Unlocked;
    // has this achievement been displayed
    public bool Displayed;
}

public class Achievements : MonoBehaviour
{
    // in general instead of many GetComponent calls use the correct type right away in the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private GameObject achievementBanner;
    [SerializeField] private Text achievementText;
    [SerializeField] private Animation achievementBannerAnimation;
    [SerializeField] private Animation achievementTextAnimation;
    [SerializeField] private Achievement[] achievements;

    // is currently a display routine running already?
    private bool currentlyDisplaying;

    private void Start()
    {
        // initially hide all objects
        foreach (var achievement in achievements)
        {
            achievement.GameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        achievementBanner.SetActive(false);
        achievementText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // if currently a display routine is running do nothing
        if (currentlyDisplaying) return;

        // otherwise go through all achievements
        foreach (var achievement in achievements)
        {
            // check if one is unlocked but hasn't been displayed yet
            if (achievement.Unlocked && !achievement.Displayed)
            {
                // set to displayed and display it
                StartCoroutine(DisplayAchievement(achievement));
                // break to only handle one at a time
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator DisplayAchievement(Achievement achievement)
    {
        // just in case if other routine is already running do nothing
        if (currentlyDisplaying) yield break;

        // block other routines from being started
        currentlyDisplaying = true;

        // set displayed so it is not displayed again
        achievement.Displayed = true;

        // Enable your objects and set the text accordingly
        achievementText.text = achievement.Label;
        achievementText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        achievementBanner.SetActive(true);
        achievement.GameObject.SetActive(true);

        achievementBannerAnimation.Play("Achievement");
        achievementTextAnimation.Play("AchiText");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(6);

        achievementBanner.SetActive(false);
        achievementText.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        // allow the next routine to start
        currentlyDisplaying = false;
    }
}
```

---

even better than poll checking within `Update` would be to rather go for events like e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class Achievement
{
    // text to display in the banner
    public string Label; 

    // the object to enable
    public GameObject GameObject;

    // has this been achieved
    // private but (de)serializable e.g. for saving via Json etc later on
    // and editable via Inspector
    [SerializeField] private bool unlocked = false;

    // public read-only access
    public bool Unlocked => unlocked;

    public void Unlock()
    {
        // is this already unlocked anyway?
        if(!unlocked)
        {
            // if not unlock and invoke event
            unlocked = true;
            OnUnlocked?.Invoke(this);
        }
    }

    // global event to subscribe to for all achievement unlocks
    public static event Action<Achievement> OnUnlocked;
}
```

and then listen to this

```
public class Achievements : MonoBehaviour
{
    // in general instead of many GetComponent calls use the correct type right away in the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private GameObject achievementBanner;
    [SerializeField] private Text achievementText;
    [SerializeField] private Animation achievementBannerAnimation;
    [SerializeField] private Animation achievementTextAnimation;
    [SerializeField] private Achievement[] achievements;

    // is currently a display routine running already?
    private bool currentlyDisplaying;

    // First-In first-out collection to work off the unlocked achievements in the UI
    private readonly Queue<Achievement> achievementsToDisplay = new ();

    private void Start()
    {
        // initially hide all objects
        foreach (var achievement in achievements)
        {
            achievement.GameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        achievementBanner.SetActive(false);
        achievementText.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        // listen to the event
        Achievement.OnUnlocked += OnAchievementUnlocked;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // to avoid exceptions unregister the listener from the event
        Achievement.OnUnlocked -= OnAchievementUnlocked;
    }

    // called everytime an achievement is unlocked
    private void OnAchievementUnlocked(Achievement achievement)
    { 
        // add achievement to the queue to work 
        achievementsToDisplay.Enqueue(achievement);

        // if there isn't a worker routine running already anyway 
        if (!currentlyDisplaying)
        {
            // start one now
            StartCoroutine(DisplayAchievements());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator DisplayAchievement()
    {
        // just in case if other routine is already running do nothing
        if (currentlyDisplaying) yield break;

        // block other routines from being started
        currentlyDisplaying = true;

        // as long as there are new achievements in the queue simply continue directly with the next one
        while(achievementsToDisplay.Count > 0)
        {
            var achievement = achievementsToDisplay.Dequeue();

            // Enable your objects and set the text accordingly
            achievementText.text = achievement.Label;
            achievementText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            achievementBanner.SetActive(true);
            achievement.GameObject.SetActive(true);

            achievementBannerAnimation.Play("Achievement");
            achievementTextAnimation.Play("AchiText");

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(6);

            achievementBanner.SetActive(false);
            achievementText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        // when queue is worked off terminate for now 
        // and allow the next routine to be started later
        currentlyDisplaying = false;
    }
}
```