# C# Coroutine only activates once, even if I have a check every six seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a cookie clicker type game for a school project and I am trying to finish the achievement system. Every time you get an achievement it adds an integer to the achievement list, and every six seconds it checks how many items are in that list and if there is more than one item in the list, it runs a coroutine to play an animation on the screen. However when I actually run it, it just goes to the latest item in the list instead of the first, and it only plays the animation once when there is more than 1 item even if the print command recognizes there are still items in the list.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Achievements : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int isrunning = 1;
    public bool checkcomplete = false;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achievementBanner;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achievementText;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achievementBannerAnimation;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achievementTextAnimation;


    [SerializeField] GameObject achiOne;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achiTwo;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achiThree;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achiFour;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achiFive;
    [SerializeField] GameObject achiSix;

    ///[SerializeField] GameObject[] AchievementList;

    public List<int> achievementlist = new List<int> ();
    ///public int[] achievementsunlock = new int[];


    [SerializeField] public static int achiementcount;
    bool achievementrec = false;
    ///bool achievementani = false;
    bool achidone = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        achiOne.SetActive(false);
        achiTwo.SetActive(false);
        achiThree.SetActive(false);
        achiFour.SetActive(false);
        achiFive.SetActive(false);
        achiSix.SetActive(false);
        achievementBanner.SetActive(false);
        achievementText.SetActive(false);
        achievementText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Achievement: First cookie!";

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        print("|");
        print(achievementlist.Count);
        print("|");
        if (isrunning == 1)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Wait());
        }
        if (checkcomplete == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(CheckAchievement());
        }
        ///print(achievementlist.Count);
        ///print(achidone);
        if (achiementcount == 1)
        {
            ///print("Test D");
            ///achiOne.SetActive(true);
            ///achievementBanner.SetActive(true);
            ///achievementText.SetActive(true);
            if (!achidone)
            {
                ///print("Test D");
                achiOne.SetActive(true);
                ///achievementBanner.SetActive(true);
                ///achievementText.SetActive(true);
                if (!achievementrec)
                {
                    achievementlist.Add(1);
                    achievementrec = true;
                }
            }
            
            ///print(achievementlist[1]);
            ///print(achievementlist[1]);
            ///StartCoroutine(AchievementGot());
            ///achidone = true;
            ///}
            ///}
        }
        if (achiementcount == 2)
        {
            achievementText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Achievement: First Clicker!";
            ///achievementrec = false;
            if (achievementrec == true)
            {
                achievementlist.Add(2);
                achievementrec = false;
            }
            ///print(achievementlist[1]);
            ///print(achievementlist[2]);
            ///print("Test C");
            achiTwo.SetActive(true);
            ///achievementBanner.SetActive(true);
            ///achievementText.SetActive(true);
            ///StartCoroutine(AchievementGot());
        }
        
        ///print(achidone);

            ///achidone = false;
        if (achiementcount == 3)
        {
            achievementText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Achievement: First Upgrade!";
            achievementlist.Add(3);
            ///achievementrec = false;
            ///print("Test A");
            achiThree.SetActive(true);
            ///achievementBanner.SetActive(true);
            ///achievementText.SetActive(true);
            ///StartCoroutine(AchievementGot());
            ///}
            ////}
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator Wait()
    {
        isrunning = 0;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);
        if (achievementlist.Count >= 1)
        {
            achievementlist.RemoveAt(0);
            print("Test A");
            print(achievementlist.Count);
            checkcomplete = true;
        }
        else
        {
            print("Test B");
            checkcomplete = false;
        }
        isrunning = 1;
    }
    IEnumerator CheckAchievement()
    {
        ///achievementlist.RemoveAt(0);
        achievementBanner.SetActive(true);
        achievementText.SetActive(true);
        ///achievementText.GetComponent<Text>().text = (achievementlist[1]);
        achievementBannerAnimation.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Achievement");
        achievementTextAnimation.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("AchiText");
        ///achievementlist.RemoveAt(0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(6);
        achievementBanner.SetActive(false);
        achievementText.SetActive(false);
        ///yield return new WaitForSeconds(6);
    }
    IEnumerator AchievementGot()
    {
        ///achievementrec = true;
        ///achievementlist.RemoveAt(1);
        ///if (achievementlist.Count == 1)
        ///{
            ///print("Test List");
            ///achievementBannerAnimation.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Achievement");
            ///achievementTextAnimation.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("AchiText");
            ///achievementlist.RemoveAt(0);
            ///achidone = true;
        ///}
        ///achievementBannerAnimation.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Achievement");
        ///achievementTextAnimation.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("AchiText");
        ///print(achievementlist[1]);
        ///print(achievementlist[2]);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(6);
        achidone = true;
        ///print(achievementlist.Contains(1));
        ///print(achievementlist.Count);
        ///if(achievementlist.Length >= 1)
        ///{
            ///print("Test F");
        ///}
        ///print("Test B");
        achievementBanner.SetActive(false);
        achievementText.SetActive(false);
        ///achievementrec = true;
    }
}
```

I use `achievementlist.RemoveAt(0)` after using the animation, so before the animation plays there are two values in the list, and then after there is one value in the list which it ignores.

Comment: This looks extremely complex again ... I wonder what spoke against using the [list approach I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74178023/7111561)

Comment: 1. Writing code like that is so fragile and repetitive, I'm tempted to just say it's plain wrong. Use an array/list and iterate it, as was explained in @derHugo's answer to your other question. 2. The logic here looks like it could be greatly simplified, but it's not worth trying to improve on that until you first implement derHugo's list suggestion.

Comment: Is there a reason you actively check every six seconds? Do you need to enforce that the animation can only play on a multiple of six seconds? If not, it would be much simpler to do the check **re**-actively--i.e. whenever you increment the counter. Then you don't even need a coroutine or timers.

Comment: `achiementcount` appears to begin at 0 and forever remain at that value.  Also, `AchievementGot` never appears to be called, why include it in the question? Please edit the question to include a [mre].

Comment: Very good point by @Tenfour04 .. I updated [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74178023/7111561) at the bottom with an event driven approach

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite this so that instead of using coroutines, you just run all of the checks from within the Update() function. If you only want to check it every 6 seconds, do it like this instead:

```
float timeSinceLastUpdate = 0; // Time in milliseconds
void Update()
{
    timeSinceLastUpdate += Time.deltaTime;
    if (timeSinceLastUpdate > 6000) // 6000 ms = 6 seconds
    {
         timeSinceLastUpdate -= 6000;
         CheckAchievements();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Time.deltaTime` is measured in seconds, not milliseconds.